# Trouble saving new post using mongoose and node / express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to save a new post to MongoDB using Mongoose and Node / Express. For me this is the missing piece to start working on a blog website using Node.

I am sharing the code from

'**routes**': posts, verifyToken, and auth
**models**: Post, User

The ERROR happens when I try to use the posts route to post.

```
{
    "errors": {
        "owner": {
            "stringValue": "\"{ iat: 1579749217 }\"",
            "kind": "ObjectID",
            "value": {
                "iat": 1579749217
            },
            "path": "owner",
            "reason": {
                "stringValue": "\"{ iat: 1579749217 }\"",
                "kind": "ObjectId",
                "value": {
                    "iat": 1579749217
                },
                "path": "owner",
                "reason": {},
                "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ iat: 1579749217 }\" at path \"owner\"",
                "name": "CastError"
            },
            "message": "Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"{ iat: 1579749217 }\" at path \"owner\"",
            "name": "CastError"
        }
    },
    "_message": "Post validation failed",
    "message": "Post validation failed: owner: Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"{ iat: 1579749217 }\" at path \"owner\"",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

posts.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const Post = require('../models/Post');
const verify = require('./verifyToken');

router.post('/', verify, async (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post({
        title: "FIRST TITLE",
        desc: "FIRST DESCRIPTION",
        owner: req.user
    })
    try {
        const newPost = await post.save();
        res.status(201).send(newPost);
    } catch(err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

auth.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/User');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const {registerValidation, loginValidation} = require('../validation');

router.post('/register', async (req,res) => {
    const {error} = registerValidation(req.body);
    if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    const emailExists =  await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if(emailExists) return res.status(400).send('Email already exists!');

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

    const user = new User({
        name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: hashedPassword
    })

    try {
        const newUser = await user.save();
        res.json(newUser);
    } catch(err) {
        res.json({message:err})
    }
})

router.post('/login', async (req,res) => {
    const {error} = loginValidation(req.body);
    if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if (!user) return res.status(400).send("email does not exist");

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if(!validPassword) return res.status(400).send("password is incorrect");

    const token = jwt.sign({_id: req.body._id}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
    res.header('auth-token', token).send(token);
})

module.exports = router;
```

verifyToken.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function tokenAuth (req,res,next){
    const token = req.header('auth-token');
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access Denied!");
    try {
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
        req.user = verified;
        next();
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(400).send('Invalid_Token');
    }
}

module.exports = tokenAuth;
```

model: User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Data = require('./Post');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 255
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 255
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 1024
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

model: Post.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        title: {
            type: String, 
            required: true,
            max: 40
        },
        desc: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            max: 100
        },
        owner: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User'
        }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

I am totally lost, every solution either doesn't work, or doesn't work with my setup!

Comment: `req.user` is not a valid mongoDB id.. Print `req.user` and see

Comment: I want the post to reference an actual user, thats why i'm using it. req.user prints the number in the Error above.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states `"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ iat: 1579749217 }\" at path \"owner\""`, the value you are trying to save while inserting a post for owner key is not a mongo id. Try adding a break point at `req.user` or consoling it to check what is the value you are getting in req.user.

Comment: Got it, I still don't know how to get it to reference an actual user (owner), thats why i'm using it. req.user prints the number in the Error above. I don't want it to be a random post, I want to query it later using the user id, since theoretically he is the one whoe made the post

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning, decoded JWT value to the user in verifyToken.js,

```
req.user = verified;
```

and when you trying to save a post written in the code in posts.js,

```
const post = new Post({
        title: "FIRST TITLE",
        desc: "FIRST DESCRIPTION",
        owner: req.user
    })
```

you are assigning the decoded value to owner which has type `ObjectId`. Please assign a valid ObjectId there. 
You can generate it using

```
new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```

or passed the ID from the decoded token `_id` in the `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`to construct an ObjectId same as present in the `User` collection.

Comment: Hey Shivam, thanks a lot :) I passed the verify._id to the objectID Params in the posts’ owner section (not post model) but now I keep getting random id numbers, shouldn’t the user have only one id?

Comment: @mobied yes user should have id same as created in User schema.You are signing the token with random id, jwt.sign({_id: req.body._id}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET); You need to pass here the user._id which you are receiving after user validation in 3 lines above in your code here.